# Javascript function parameters checking

Tags: javascript, json, function

I have a function with 4 parameters for building json request. I need to check parameters for 'undefined'/empty value

```
function funName(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
       if (param1 !== '' && param2 !== '' && param3 !== '' && param4 !== '') {
          url = https://example.com/api/posts.json?' + param1 + param2 + param3 + param4; 
       }
       else if {
       if (param1 == '' && param2 !== '' && param3 !== '' && param4 !== '') {
          url = https://example.com/api/posts.json?' + param2 + param3 + param4;
       }
       // code
    };
```

How to check more elegant ?

Comment: `params = [...arguments].filter(x => x).join('')`

Comment: That code has several mistakes: `function` keyword missing, arguments with duplicate names, missing quotes, and you'd better not use `url` as a global variable. That should be dealt with before thinking of making it more elegant. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry, I'm in a hurry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purposes you can do this:

```
function funName(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
   var url = 'https://example.com/api/posts.json?' + 
             (param1 || '') + (param2 || '') + (param3 || '') + (param4 || '');
   // rest of your code.
}
```

Or with ES6:

```js
function funName(/* params */) {
   var url = 'https://example.com/api/posts.json?' + 
             [...arguments].filter(p => p).join('');
   // rest of your code.
   console.log(url);
}

funName('a=1', '&b=2', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend iterating over the `arguments` object to do this:

```
funName(param1, param1, param1, param1) {
    url = 'https://example.com/api/posts.json?';
    var i;

    for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] && arguments[i] !== '') {
            url += arguments[i];
        }
    }

    // code

}
```

This code will work with an indeterminate number of arguments.  If you are confident of the amount of arguments being passed in, you could omit the `arguments` bit and instead just make an array of all the arguments, and iterate over that array.

Please note that, unless you are passing in fully formed query parameters as arguments-- complete with separators-- this might not actually work out of the box.  I'm not sure what the actual passed arguments look like so I can't say for sure.

Comment: Doh! Thanks @Feathercrown - that's fixed now.

Comment: And the url isn't in a fully enclosed string. Other than that, nice!

Comment: You're welcome. Simple mistakes happen all the time!

Comment: @Feathercrown - can I hire you to review my work at my job?  This would solve a lot of issues for me... :)

Comment: Thanks for the thanks! I couldn't though, I'm only 15. XD

Comment: Yeah, I could see where that would pose a labor laws violation issue.  Keep up the good work-- a career in development awaits!

Comment: Thanks again! That's exactly what I'm planning to go into!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to add each argument of the function if it has a value... Also, each formal argument (param1, param1, etc) has the same name ... they should be unique!

```js
function funName(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
  var url = 'https://example.com/api/posts.json?';
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments,function(argumentItem) {
    if (argumentItem) {
      url += argumentItem;
    }
  });
  return url;
}
console.log(funName('', 'a', 'n', 'c'));
```